# Keras metric produces infinite result in K.mean

Tags: keras, backend, metrics, keras-2

EDIT: It was actually a divide-by-zero error. :(

I created a metric function in Keras to calculate the average fractional error; that is, for each actual/predicted pair I calculate *abs(actual - predicted)/actual*, then find the mean across all the data. The code is below.

```
def avg_frac_error(y_actual, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_actual - y_pred)/ y_actual)
```

When applying the metric on a small dataset (say 6,000 scalar values), the result is produced accurately. When calculating it on a larger one (10,000 values) the result is *inf*. I suspect that it's failing at the K.mean, as the same occurs when I try to calculate the mean manually. I have tested both tensorflow and theano backends.

What workaround could I do to calculate the mean?

Comment: You probably have already checked, but are you sure there are no 0's, or nearly so, values in `y_actual` ?

Comment: Oh, dang. I knew it had to be something obvious. Thanks.